# MailJet Api - getting message information about sent email

Tags: api, mailjet

I have sent a transaction email day ago via mailjet api, how do I check info about that message, it works for some messageIDs but for others or most of them it returns 404 error. Maybe  I'm doing something wrong.

It says mailjet stores and gives such info for up to 90 days?

Since I am on a free plan, they closed my question case, so looking for anwsers anywhere else :/

```
MessageUUID:731f3280-b140-4cdc-a3a8-33c314d4e6f8
MessageID:576460762915860600

curl -X GET --user ***:*** https://api.mailjet.com/v3/REST/message/576460762915860600

{ "ErrorInfo" : "", "ErrorMessage" : "Object not found", "StatusCode" : 404 }

curl -X GET --user ***:*** https://api.mailjet.com/v3/REST/messageinformation/576460762915860600

{ "ErrorInfo" : "", "ErrorMessage" : "Object not found", "StatusCode" : 404 }
```

Comment: did u find reasons for this?

Answer (score 0):

You are likely specifying a version of Mailjet's API that doesn't implement the message information retrieval endpoint.

**If you omit the version when instantiating the wrapper or check with their swagger for a compatible version, it should be fine.**

Note that returning a `404` is a dubious choice on Mailjet's side.
Returning the more helpful `501 Not Implemented` and reserving `404 Not Found` to actually missing objects would have helped here.